# Three.js - Exporting obj files with python

Tags: python, three.js

I thought I'd post this here because hours of googling ended up fruitless. I have an obj file and I'm trying to use the python script included with three.js to export it for use in three.js however I have never used python before and don't know what I'm doing.

These have been my steps so far:
I've opened up the Python GUI, opened up `convert_obj_three.py`, clicked `run -> run module`,  and then I get this:

```
======= RESTART: C:\three.js\utils\converters\obj\convert_obj_three.py =======
Usage: convert_obj_three.py -i filename.obj -o filename.js [-m morphfiles*.obj] [-c morphcolors*.obj] [-a center|top|bottom] [-s flat|smooth] [-t binary|ascii] [-d invert|normal]
```

When I try typing in something like `convert_obj_three.py -i test.obj -o test.js` I get an `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error.

test.obj is in the same folder as convert_obj_three.py however that does not seem to be the issue as no matter what I type I seem to get a syntax error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command:

```
convert_obj_three.py -i test.obj -o test.js
```

at a command prompt. On Windows, Python will have to be in your path for this to work, that's an option in the installer (at least in 2.7) right at the bottom of the list of options, IME sometimes not visible - very easy to miss - so scroll down to find it.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but when you say command prompt - Do you mean the windows command prompt or the python command prompt? Do I need to load convert_obj_three.py somehow first? Or do I need to include the full path to convert_obj_three.py (c:\three.js\utils\converters\obj\convert_obj_three.py)?

Comment: Yes open a windows command prompt, cd to the folder where convert_obj_three.py is, and use paths to the obj and js file as needed (i.e. if they are in same folder no path is needed)